# Improving Gremlin Server Command Evaluation Performance

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

When inserting tens of thousands of nodes and edges into a cassandra-backed tinkerpop I see basically all services are mostly idle except the Gremlin Server.  That is, the client connected to the websocket and sending the Gremlin formatted commands is not consuming much CPU time and neither is Cassandra or ElasticSearch.  Gremlin Server, on the other hand, is consuming several CPUs (on a rather beefy machine with dozens of cores and hundreds of gigabytes of RAM).

Increasing the number of GS worker threads doesn't have a positive impact.  Increasing the number of simultaneous websocket requests permitted (a client setting) also does not help.  Oddly, an unbounded number of concurrent websocket requests results in data failing to be inserted without any HTTP error message responses.

The working theory is that gremlin server's bottleneck is evaluation of the Gremlin commands (g.addV, etc).  Does anyone have experience getting high ingest rates using the websocket plugin or is it necessary for me to write my own JVM langauge plugin that works on binary data to avoid parsing and evaluation of strings?

EDIT: The scripts are batches of up to 100 statements of either vertex insertions or edge/vertex/edge insertions:

The vertex insertions:

```
graph.addVertex(label, tyParam, 'ident', vertexName, param1, val1, param2, val2 ...) ;
graph.addVertex(...) ; 
...
```

For triples of edge, vertex, edge:

```
edgeNode = graph.addVertex(...) ; 
g.V().has('ident',var).next().addEdge(var2,edgeNode) ;
edgeNode.addEdge(var3, g.V().has('ident',var4).next())
```

'ident' is node indexed so that `.has` should be fast.  Sadly, the dataset includes edges for sources or destinations that do not exist, causing "FastNoSuchElementException" errors.  In error cases we split the set of statements in half and retry the script as two smaller insertion attempts.  For example, a script of 50 edge/vertex/edge insertion statements failing becomes two scripts of 25 and this process continues all the way down to a script with a single e/v/e insertion where any failure is ignored.

N.B. I'm using Titan 1.0.

Comment: Are you using parameterized scripts? http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#parameterized-scripts

Comment: Yes, the scripts are all parameterized.

Comment: you mentioned "GS worker threads" - which specific setting are you referring to when you say that?

Comment: @stephenmallette I was referring to "threadPoolWorker" and "gremlinPool" configuration parameters not having any notable impact.  <4 cores used at any given time.

Comment: hmmm. i would expect gremlinPool to have an impact. i've recently changed the default to be Runtime.availableProcessors() instead of the hardcoded value we used to have as that sometimes left folks who put gremlin server on machines with lots of core underutilized because they didn't adjust the default.

Comment: @stephenmallette By "not having a notable impact" I should say that increasing the thread count (gremlinPool) does not cause us to consume more than 4 cores and Cassandra remains bored.  Even an excessive `gremlinPool=260` doesn't get us over this hump.

Comment: hmm - what is the nature of the scripts you submit to Gremlin Server? mostly read? write? long run? short run?

Comment: @stephenmallette I'll update the question win an edit in a minute.  The scripts are 1, 25, 50 or 100 statements of: `graph.addVertex(label, tyParam, 'ident', vertexName, param1, val1, param2, val2 ...) ; graph.addVertex(...) ; ...` or adding a triples of edge, node, edge: `edgeNode = graph.addVertex(...) ; g.V().has('ident',var).next().addEdge(var2,edgeNode) ; edgeNode.addEdge(var3, g.V().has('ident',var4).next())`.

Comment: The cost of script evaluation is fairly low. The cost is all in the first evaluation, after which the compiled script is cached and future calls on that script should be on par with regular binary execution. Under the loading model you described you only have 4 scripts that gremlin server ever has to compile "for the first time" (which is why @JasonPlurad asked about parameterization). I assume that the individual 1,25,50,100 scripts submitted each time are identical even down to variable name - if so, then that's all good. Are you using the java driver? or loading from a non-jvm language?

Comment: @stephenmallette Thank you.  While in principle I understood the script parameterization was for caching I seem to have not put that knowledge to use properly.  Each `addVertex` command could vary in numbers of parameters and would thus be a different script.  For example, in batches of 100 with just two different possible parameter counts for vertices it mean 2^100 possible scripts - no caching will occur.  I can write up a quick answer or you could if you'd like and I'd happily accept it.  One mystery remains is why GS memory use remained flat - shouldn't the script cache have exploded?

Comment: If you can adjust your scripts to make better use of parameterization, you should see better increases in throughput. I'm not sure why you didn't see increased memory usage over time. I would have likely expected that, unless you were getting some cache hits along the way somewhere that allowed you some re-use on some requests. If you are on Titan 1.0 i'm wondering if we used to default to soft references in the script cache which would have theoretically prevented an OutOfMemoryException - but i can't recall if that was the case.

Comment: If better script parameterization fixes your problem perhaps @JasonPlurad should write the answer and get credit - he sorta called it right from the outset. :) if not, i can write one up.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but if somebody beats me to posting a solid answer, it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to do [script parameterization](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#parameterized-scripts) for the best performance in Gremlin Server. Without that, the server cannot effectively utilize its script cache, and every script that is processed ends up having to be compiled which is typically one of the more expensive parts of a request. Note that for the script cache to work, scripts must be identical in every way in their text to even include variable names. In other words:

```
g.V(var1)
g.V(var2)
```

are not identical because they have different variable names and therefore will not take advantage of the script cache.

In the event that it is not possible to make scripts identical, then it would be smart to submit such scripts with the `#jsr223.groovy.engine.keep.globals` request parameter set to something other than `hard` (i.e. `soft`, `weak` or `phantom`) so that Gremlin Server can reclaim memory from the script cache as more new scripts arrive.